# Scheme and C working together

Tags: c, scheme

Is there a way to have C run scheme programs? I know both languages and was hoping to use the logic of scheme with the speed of C. A basic example C makes the lists that scheme needs to use then scheme returns something. So far I have been using DrRacket for scheme. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

edit:

Looking at Caleb's answer I saw Racket CGC. How do you find this I have the racket source from its website, I am on Ubuntu. And where can i get the libracket.a and libmzgc.a libraries. I can't find them anywhere. Everywhere I look it just points back to the article saying you need them.

Comment: [GNU Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) is another embeddable Scheme...

Comment: Have you looked at chicken scheme? http://www.call-cc.org

Comment: If it's possible in your case, it's far easier if you put Scheme in control and have it call into C libraries when necessary. See soegaard's answer.

Comment: I totally second (third?) Ryan's seconding of Jens Soegaard's answer. It sounds like you have a program, and you want parts of it to run faster. That's a totally legitimate issue, but you'll probably get better answers if you're specific about the thing that's too slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way of mixing Scheme and C is to write the main program in Scheme and only write what absolutely needs to be in C in C.

The C source is compiled as a library, and then it is imported in Racket using the FFI. The FFI is surprisingly easy to use, and even if you decide to write your program the other way around, is definitely something you should examine first.

[Introduction to the FFI](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/intro.html)

[Docs on the FFI](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/index.html)

Btw - libracket.a and libmzgc.a should be installed along with the rest of the Racket files. I am not on Ubuntu, so I don't know the exact path. However you can use the unix command `find` to locate it.

If I remember correctly, the command is:

```
find / -name libracket.a
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [the Racket C API documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/index.html), particularly the section titled [Embedding Racket into a Program](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/overview.html#%28part._embedding%29)? Instructions are provided there for Unix, Windows, and MacOS X.

Answer (score 4):

Most current schemes have some sort of foreign function interface that will allow you to work with non-scheme code.  Lot's of people here have more experience with Racket than I do, so I will let them tell you about that.

[Chicken](http://www.call-cc.org) is rather unique among schemes in that it includes a compiler to `C`.  As such, chicken allows you to directly embed `C` code into a scheme program with these `#> ... <#` and has several procedures for [interfacing with external variables and functions](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Interface%20to%20external%20functions%20and%20variables).

Please consult the '[Getting Started](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Getting%20started)' section of the manual for more information.